# Fenchel conjugate of the cumulant function (Exponential Family)

Tags: exponential-family, cumulants

We have a minimal exponential family $f(x) = h(x) \exp(\langle\theta, t(x)\rangle - A(\theta)).$ The canonical parameter space is $\Theta = \{ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^d \colon \int h(x) \exp(\langle\theta, t(x)\rangle) < \infty \}.$ Our family is regular, which means $\Theta$ is open.

We have that $A$ is strictly convex on $\Theta$, which is a convex set. And $A$ is continuous on the interior of $\Theta$, and it is actually smooth in the sense that all of its gradient exists.

We also know that the map sending $\theta$ to $\nabla A(\theta)$ is one-to-one on $\Theta$.

We define Fenchel conjugate to be $A^*(t) = \sup \{\langle\theta, t\rangle - A(\theta) \colon \theta \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$.

A statement in our note is that $A^*(t) < \infty$ if and only if $t = \nabla A(\theta)$ for some $\theta$.

Now, $t = \nabla A(\theta)$ implies $A^*(t) < \infty$ is clear, but $A^*(t) < \infty$ implies the other way around is not clear.

A bounded concave function on an open set may not attain its maximum on the open set, so I'm not sure how to prove the $A*(t) < \infty$ implies $t = \nabla A(\theta)$ for some $\theta$.

Comment: thank you for this fascinating question. Out of curiosity, can you share how you stumbled into it?

Comment: @JohnMadden it is from our class notes.